# Bubble Sort Algorithm Difference

Tags: java, sorting

What is the difference between these two code blocks first one is conventional bubble sort implementation whereas, I created different type of bubble sort my question is where is the difference and why?

```
public int[] sort_bubbleSort(int[] nums){
  for (int i=0; i < nums.length-1; i++){
    for (int j=0; j < nums.length-1-i; j++)
      if (nums[j] > nums[j+1]) {
        int temp = nums[j];
        nums[j] = nums[j+1];
        nums[j+1] = temp;
      }
    }
  return nums;
}
```

```
public int[] sort_bubbleSort(int[] nums){
  for(int left = 0; left<nums.length; left++) {
    for(int right =left+1; right<nums.length; right++) {
      if(nums[left] > nums[right]) {
        int temp = nums[left];
        nums[left] = nums[right];
        nums[right] = temp;
      }
    }
  }return nums;
}
```

Comment: But why? I think both of them have n^2 complexity. Whats the difference in terms of efficiency?

Comment: I said nothing about complexity or efficiency... by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) Bubble Sort works by "comparing the current element with the one after it" - second code snippet is not doing that (seems like it is the *I can't believe it can sort*  algorithm also mentioned on that Wikipedia page, more like insertion sort)

Comment: @user16320675 It's none of those.

Comment: @user16320675 I mean it's neither "I can't believe it can sort" nor something like insertion sort.

Comment: @user16320675 What do you mean with an example? And not sure what you mean with "being like" vs "being a".

Comment: @user16320675 It's in the paper (which Wikipedia referenced, so I thought you had seen it). Why do you think this one here is like insertion sort? It neither looks nor behaves like it at all.

Comment: (1-) *I created different type of bubble sort* - if you created it what did YOU change and WHY?

Answer (score -1):

Both implementations are using nested loops. In the first case, the outer loop iterates through the array and the inner loop iterates through the array from the beginning until the end minus the number of elements that have already been sorted. The result is that with each iteration of the outer loop, the largest element in the unsorted part of the array "bubbles up" to its correct position at the end of the array.

In your implementation it iterates through the array so that, instead of keeping track of the end of the unsorted part of the array, it simply compares each element with every other element that comes after it. This means that each iteration of the outer loop simply swaps the current element with the next smallest element in the array.

First implementation requires fewer iterations because it stops iterating through the array as soon as it reaches the end of the unsorted part. Your implementation, on the other hand, always iterates through the entire array, even if the array is already sorted.

In terms of efficiency, the first implementation would be faster than your implementation (in case of larger arrays), however if you are working with small array, both of them would be fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).